# Problem fetching contact container Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.ios

I got a problem with a little application I'm developing using Xamarin.iOS

My goal is simply to get every contacts present on an iPhone.

I have this code, it worked until now on my phone and at least 3 others.
Yesterday I added someone in my provisioning profile, since, I can't get any other value than 'null' on my phone when I try to fetch a container.

My phone is an iPhone 7 iOS 13.1.2 - I can't test it on any other phone until a little moment.

It still works on a simulator (iPhone 8 iOS 13.1).

I have the contact authorization request in my info.plist.
I just don't understand what getting 'null' means when fetching a default container ...

```
try
        {
            var keysTOFetch = new[] { CNContactKey.GivenName, CNContactKey.FamilyName, CNContactKey.Nickname, CNContactKey.JobTitle, CNContactKey.DepartmentName, CNContactKey.OrganizationName, CNContactKey.PostalAddresses, CNContactKey.UrlAddresses, CNContactKey.EmailAddresses, CNContactKey.PhoneNumbers };
            NSError error;
            CNContact[] contactList;
            var ContainerId = new CNContactStore().DefaultContainerIdentifier;  <---- //This where I get a null I never got before ...
            if (ContainerId != null)
            {
                using (var predicate = CNContact.GetPredicateForContactsInContainer(ContainerId))
                using (var store = new CNContactStore())
                    contactList = store.GetUnifiedContacts(predicate, keysTOFetch, out error);
                var contacts = new List<UserContact>();
                status = writeCSV(contactList, user);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Didn't get any container identifier ..");
        }
```

Apple documentation says it can return 'null' but without further explanation ..

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this issue on some phones and not other because the phone that work have only one container that it is trying load contacts from, while the phones that don't work have more than one container (i.e. Gmail, Exchange, iCloud accounts used to store contacts). So you are only loading the contacts from the account that is configured as the default, which has 0 contacts. Therefore, it would not load all contacts as requested.

Solution: Get all the containers and iterate over them to extract all contacts from each of them. You might be able to find some samples of it on [Github](https://github.com/twdean/Inner/blob/5fad4576f1624a6c3337551b5197e8f346e00c30/Inner/iOS/Classes/ContactHelper.cs).